# Delete a Discord message if it doesn't start with "!test"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the bot to delete the message if it doesn't have the command **!test**

```
client.on("message", function(message) {
  if (message.channel.id === '823216214737289266') return;
  if (input.indexOf("!test") != -1) {
      if (J===null) {
          setTimeout(function() {
                bot.deleteMessage(message);
          }, 1000);
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method to check if the message content starts with the argument provided. You could also just simply delete the message using `message.delete()`:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.channel.id === '823216214737289266') return;

  if (!message.content.startsWith('!test')) {
    // not sure what J is, so leaving it here
    if (J === null) {
      setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: if (!message.startsWith('!test')) {
               ^

TypeError: message.startsWith is not a function

Comment: I've updated it a couple of minutes ago ;)

Comment: if (J === null) {
    ^

ReferenceError: J is not defined

Comment: Well, it was in your original code and I'm not sure what that is. If you don't need it, you can safely remove those.

Comment: The answer Zsolt has provided is correct, if you don't know your own code that's a different issue.